# What R function can I use to sum two columns and save the new variable as a new column?

Tags: r, sum, col

I summed two colums, Sweden.pymen and Swede.pywomen, and created Sweden.pyall - the entries are numbers. This is the code i used:

```
Sweden_py.all <- (Sweden$py.men + Sweden$py.women)
```

I got this as a result:
[image]

but i need to have it stored as a column with one value under the other and not all in the same cell.

Any help would be great! Cheers

Comment: Sweden$py.all <- (Sweden$py.men + Sweden$py.women)

Comment: Equivalent of `.` from `Python` in `R` is `$` to define a variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `dplyr::mutate` for this:

```r
require(dplyr)

Sweden <- Sweden %>%
mutate(py.all = py.men + py.women)
```

You should check out this intro for basic data wrangling: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/dplyr.html